# Element that is not inside of other element

Tags: css, css-selectors

If you have this HTML

```
<div>
    <span class="style-me">i want to be styled</span>
</div>
<div class="ignore-my-descendants">
    <span class="style-me">i want to be styled but my parent prevents it</span>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

then this CSS selector

```
.style-me:not(.ignore-my-descendants *) {
    color: red;
}
```

will not match anything. Maybe because :not() only accepts simple selectors which is not given here (I'm not sure, hope you can tell me the true reason).
Is there a pure css way to filter out those elements that have a parent matching a given criteria?

EDIT: i don't want to apply any values to the elements to be ignored.
This is important because the desired `display` property value of an element cannot be foreseen.

Comment: Correct, it's because `:not()` only accepts simple selectors as of CSS3.

Answer (score 4):

umm... you are selecting a child and asking to match its parent. Won't work

There is an easy way

```
.style-me {
    color: red;
}

.ignore-my-descendants .style-me {
        color: white;
    }
```

Comment: The Problem with this solution is that i have to set a style for those that i want to ignore. This will bring heavy problems when using properties like display:none for the styled item because you can't know the previous value of the element.

Maybe my Question should be "is there a selector to select those elements which are NOT inside of another given element"